# Phantom - RPC Error -32603 only on production?

Tags: metaplex, nft, rpc, phantom, sugar

I was following a guide on buildspace and the application worked perfectly. It was a Solana NFT minter working perfect with Phantom in localhost. But after I hosted it on Vercel, I started getting this weird unknown error.  Does anyone have a solution or idea on how I can get a deeper description on this error?
[image: Photo of my console and wallet]

**Mint Token function (causes error)**

```
const mintToken = async () => {
        const mint = web3.Keypair.generate();

        const userTokenAccountAddress = (await getAtaForMint(mint.publicKey, walletAddress.publicKey))[0];

        const userPayingAccountAddress = candyMachine.state.tokenMint
            ? (await getAtaForMint(candyMachine.state.tokenMint, walletAddress.publicKey))[0]
            : walletAddress.publicKey;

        const candyMachineAddress = candyMachine.id;
        const remainingAccounts = [];
        const signers = [mint];
        const cleanupInstructions = [];
        const instructions = [
            web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
              fromPubkey: walletAddress.publicKey,
              newAccountPubkey: mint.publicKey,
              space: MintLayout.span,
              lamports:
                await candyMachine.program.provider.connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(
                  MintLayout.span,
                ),
              programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            }),
            Token.createInitMintInstruction(
              TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
              mint.publicKey,
              0,
              walletAddress.publicKey,
              walletAddress.publicKey,
            ),
            createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
              userTokenAccountAddress,
              walletAddress.publicKey,
              walletAddress.publicKey,
              mint.publicKey,
            ),
            Token.createMintToInstruction(
              TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
              mint.publicKey,
              userTokenAccountAddress,
              walletAddress.publicKey,
              [],
              1,
            ),
          ];

        if (candyMachine.state.gatekeeper) {
            remainingAccounts.push({
                pubkey: (await getNetworkToken(walletAddress.publicKey, candyMachine.state.gatekeeper.gatekeeperNetwork))[0],
                isWritable: true,
                isSigner: false,
            });
            if (candyMachine.state.gatekeeper.expireOnUse) {
                remainingAccounts.push({
                    pubkey: CIVIC,
                    isWritable: false,
                    isSigner: false,
                });
                remainingAccounts.push({
                    pubkey: (await getNetworkExpire(candyMachine.state.gatekeeper.gatekeeperNetwork))[0],
                    isWritable: false,
                    isSigner: false,
                });
            }
        }
        if (candyMachine.state.whitelistMintSettings) {
            const mint = new web3.PublicKey(candyMachine.state.whitelistMintSettings.mint);

            const whitelistToken = (await getAtaForMint(mint, walletAddress.publicKey))[0];
            remainingAccounts.push({
                pubkey: whitelistToken,
                isWritable: true,
                isSigner: false,
            });

            if (candyMachine.state.whitelistMintSettings.mode.burnEveryTime) {
                const whitelistBurnAuthority = web3.Keypair.generate();

                remainingAccounts.push({
                    pubkey: mint,
                    isWritable: true,
                    isSigner: false,
                });
                remainingAccounts.push({
                    pubkey: whitelistBurnAuthority.publicKey,
                    isWritable: false,
                    isSigner: true,
                });
                signers.push(whitelistBurnAuthority);
                const exists = await candyMachine.program.provider.connection.getAccountInfo(whitelistToken);
                if (exists) {
                    instructions.push(
                        Token.createApproveInstruction(
                            TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                            whitelistToken,
                            whitelistBurnAuthority.publicKey,
                            walletAddress.publicKey,
                            [],
                            1
                        )
                    );
                    cleanupInstructions.push(Token.createRevokeInstruction(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, whitelistToken, walletAddress.publicKey, []));
                }
            }
        }

        if (candyMachine.state.tokenMint) {
            const transferAuthority = web3.Keypair.generate();

            signers.push(transferAuthority);
            remainingAccounts.push({
                pubkey: userPayingAccountAddress,
                isWritable: true,
                isSigner: false,
            });
            remainingAccounts.push({
                pubkey: transferAuthority.publicKey,
                isWritable: false,
                isSigner: true,
            });

            instructions.push(
                Token.createApproveInstruction(
                    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                    userPayingAccountAddress,
                    transferAuthority.publicKey,
                    walletAddress.publicKey,
                    [],
                    candyMachine.state.price.toNumber()
                )
            );
            cleanupInstructions.push(
                Token.createRevokeInstruction(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, userPayingAccountAddress, walletAddress.publicKey, [])
            );
        }
        const metadataAddress = await getMetadata(mint.publicKey);
        const masterEdition = await getMasterEdition(mint.publicKey);

        const [candyMachineCreator, creatorBump] = await getCandyMachineCreator(candyMachineAddress);

        instructions.push(
            await candyMachine.program.instruction.mintNft(creatorBump, {
                accounts: {
                    candyMachine: candyMachineAddress,
                    candyMachineCreator,
                    payer: walletAddress.publicKey,
                    wallet: candyMachine.state.treasury,
                    mint: mint.publicKey,
                    metadata: metadataAddress,
                    masterEdition,
                    mintAuthority: walletAddress.publicKey,
                    updateAuthority: walletAddress.publicKey,
                    tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
                    tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                    systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
                    rent: web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
                    clock: web3.SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY,
                    recentBlockhashes: web3.SYSVAR_RECENT_BLOCKHASHES_PUBKEY,
                    instructionSysvarAccount: web3.SYSVAR_INSTRUCTIONS_PUBKEY,
                },
                remainingAccounts: remainingAccounts.length > 0 ? remainingAccounts : undefined,
            })
        );

        try {
            return (
                await sendTransactions(
                    candyMachine.program.provider.connection,
                    candyMachine.program.provider.wallet,
                    [instructions, cleanupInstructions],
                    [signers, []]
                )
            ).txs.map((t) => t.txid);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        return [];
    };
```

**rest of code above it**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Connection, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { Program, AnchorProvider, web3 } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { MintLayout, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, Token } from "@solana/spl-token";
import { sendTransactions } from "./connection";

import {
    candyMachineProgram,
    TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
    SPL_ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_PROGRAM_ID,
    getAtaForMint,
    getNetworkExpire,
    getNetworkToken,
    CIVIC,
} from "./helpers";
import CountdownTimer from "../CountdownTimer";

const { SystemProgram } = web3;
const opts = {
    preflightCommitment: "processed",
};

const CandyMachine = ({ walletAddress }) => {
    const [candyMachine, setCandyMachine] = useState(null);
    const [isbeforeTime, setIsbeforeTime] = useState(null);
    const getCandyMachineCreator = async (candyMachine) => {
        const candyMachineID = new PublicKey(candyMachine);
        return await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress([Buffer.from("candy_machine"), candyMachineID.toBuffer()], candyMachineProgram);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(candyMachine)
    })
    useEffect(() => {
        getCandyMachineState();
    }, []);
    const getProvider = () => {
        const rpcHost = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SOLANA_RPC_HOST;
        // Create a new connection object
        const connection = new Connection(rpcHost);
        
        // Create a new Solana provider object
        const provider = new AnchorProvider(
          connection,
          window.solana,
          opts.preflightCommitment
        );
      
        return provider;
      };

const getCandyMachineState = async () => {
    const provider = getProvider();
    
    const idl = await Program.fetchIdl(candyMachineProgram, provider);
  
    const program = new Program(idl, candyMachineProgram, provider);
  
    const candyMachine = await program.account.candyMachine.fetch(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CANDY_MACHINE_ID
    );
    
    const itemsAvailable = candyMachine.data.itemsAvailable.toNumber();
    const itemsRedeemed = candyMachine.itemsRedeemed.toNumber();
    const itemsRemaining = itemsAvailable - itemsRedeemed;
    const goLiveData = candyMachine.data.goLiveDate.toNumber();
    const presale =
      candyMachine.data.whitelistMintSettings &&
      candyMachine.data.whitelistMintSettings.presale &&
      (!candyMachine.data.goLiveDate ||
        candyMachine.data.goLiveDate.toNumber() > new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    
    // We will be using this later in our UI so let's generate this now
    const goLiveDateTimeString = `${new Date(
      goLiveData * 1000
    ).toGMTString()}`
  
    setCandyMachine({
        id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CANDY_MACHINE_ID,
        program,
        state: {
          itemsAvailable,
          itemsRedeemed,
          itemsRemaining,
          goLiveData,
          goLiveDateTimeString,
          isSoldOut: itemsRemaining === 0,
          isActive:
            (presale ||
              candyMachine.data.goLiveDate.toNumber() < new Date().getTime() / 1000) &&
            (candyMachine.endSettings
              ? candyMachine.endSettings.endSettingType.date
                ? candyMachine.endSettings.number.toNumber() > new Date().getTime() / 1000
                : itemsRedeemed < candyMachine.endSettings.number.toNumber()
              : true),
          isPresale: presale,
          goLiveDate: candyMachine.data.goLiveDate,
          treasury: candyMachine.wallet,
          tokenMint: candyMachine.tokenMint,
          gatekeeper: candyMachine.data.gatekeeper,
          endSettings: candyMachine.data.endSettings,
          whitelistMintSettings: candyMachine.data.whitelistMintSettings,
          hiddenSettings: candyMachine.data.hiddenSettings,
          price: candyMachine.data.price,
        },
      });
    
    console.log({
      itemsAvailable,
      itemsRedeemed,
      itemsRemaining,
      goLiveData,
      goLiveDateTimeString,
    });
  };
    const getMetadata = async (mint) => {
        return (
            await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
                [Buffer.from("metadata"), TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(), mint.toBuffer()],
                TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
            )
        )[0];
    };

    const getMasterEdition = async (mint) => {
        return (
            await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
                [Buffer.from("metadata"), TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(), mint.toBuffer(), Buffer.from("edition")],
                TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
            )
        )[0];
    };

    const createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction = (associatedTokenAddress, payer, walletAddress, splTokenMintAddress) => {
        const keys = [
            { pubkey: payer, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
            { pubkey: associatedTokenAddress, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
            { pubkey: walletAddress, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
            { pubkey: splTokenMintAddress, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
            {
                pubkey: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                isSigner: false,
                isWritable: false,
            },
            { pubkey: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
            {
                pubkey: web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
                isSigner: false,
                isWritable: false,
            },
        ];
        return new web3.TransactionInstruction({
            keys,
            programId: SPL_ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_PROGRAM_ID,
            data: Buffer.from([]),
        });
    };
```

Comment: If you click the name of the file on the top right of the error you could potentially set a breakpoint and analyse what went wrong.